# R - Multiple Conditional Looping and Flagging

Tags: r, dataframe, data-modeling

Need help in running the R code for the below sample scenario:

Set 1:

```
Enc     CPT     Paid Status 
23345   97110   Paid    
23345   97140   Non Paid
23349   99396   Paid
23349   36415   Non Paid
23349   99000   Non Paid
23354   99203O  Non Paid
23367   73030   Non Paid
23367   99024   Non Paid
23372   99213O  Paid
23372   36416   Non Paid
23382   81002   Non Paid
```

Set 2:

```
Main_CPT  Child_CPT
97110     36591
97110     36592
97110     99186
97140     36591
97140     36592
97140     97124
97140     99186
36415     36591
36415     36592
99396     36591
99396     36592
99396     94002
99396     94003
73030     36591
73030     99024
81002     94002
81002     94003
```

output:

```
Enc     CPT     Paid Status    Flag
23345   97110   Paid           Paid Already
23345   97140   Non Paid       Adjusted
23349   99396   Paid           Paid Already
23349   36415   Non Paid       Adjusted
23349   99000   Non Paid       Not Applicable
23354   99203O  Non Paid       Not in Main CPT
23367   73030   Non Paid       Not Paid
23367   99024   Non Paid       Review
23372   99213O  Paid           Not in Main CPT
23372   36416   Non Paid       Not in Main CPT
23382   81002   Non Paid       Not Paid
```

Model Criteria:  Enc group Wise

1. Grouping Enc wise, if any CPT matched with Main_CPT:

   a) and its Paid Status is "P" : Flag= "Paid Already"

   i) Remaining CPT for that Enc. group matched with Child_CPT irrespective 
         of Paid Status: Flag="Adjusted"

   ii) Remaining CPT for that Enc. group mismatched with Child_CPT 
          irrespective of Paid Status: Flag="Not Applicable"

   b) and its paid Status is "NP": Flag= "Not Paid"

   i) Remaining CPT for that Enc. group matched with Child_CPT irrespective 
         of Paid Status: Flag="Review"

   ii) Remaining CPT for that Enc. group mismatched with Child_CPT 
          irrespective of Paid Status: Flag="Not Applicable"
2. if any CPT in that enc. group is mismatched with Main_CPT irrespective of any condition: Flag= "Not in Main CPT"

Comment: Can you provide the expected output?

Comment: In the 1st data set, from the enc no. 23349 having 3 observations with 3 unique CPT codes, one of the code should match with the Main CPT of the 2nd data set and the that corresponding CPT from the 1st data set status is paid!, then flag the CPT with "P" and the remaining CPT codes fot that particular Enc no. has to match with Child CPT of the 2nd data set, and that CPT has to be flagged with "A".

Comment: Expected output as in "how the final dataset would actually look like"

Comment: Enc     CPT     Paid Status    Flag
23349   99396   Paid             P           
23349   36415   Non Paid     A
23349   99000   Non Paid     NF                                                                     # in Enc 23349, CPT 99396 is matched with Main_CPT in 2nd data set and the status in 1st Data set status is Paid, hence flaged "P". For the same enc. no and with remaining CPT 36415 if found in child CPT of that corresponding Main_CPT and status is Non Paid, then flag as "A" , if not found in child CPT for that corresponding Main_CPT, then flag as "NF".

Comment: Please edit it into your question, instead of providing it in the comment section.

Comment: See my edits to your question and check if this is exactly how you want the expected output to be. You can add more rows by editing it

Comment: In your example, CPT 99396 did not match `Main_CPT`, and 36415 did not match `Child_CPT`. Can you update your Set 1 and Set 2 so that there is actually a match?

Comment: I have updated the data point for your reference. Kindly, revert with the code plz.

Comment: Really wanted to help, but still needed some clarification...99396 matches both Main_CPT _and_ Child_CPT. Is this expected?

Comment: Yeah it may match (I have intentionally mapped that)...if u can closely look at my criteria, 1st: Each enc. wise mapping. 2nd: If any of the CPT in that enc. no. of 1st set matches with MainCPT of 2nd set and if it is paid? 3rd: then remaining CPT for that enc should match with child CPT of 2nd set and then flag has to be created as "A". 4th: If not matched with Child CPT, then flag as "NF". Move to next enc and same criteria continues. Hope, I made clarification

Comment: Check my answer, you might want to test it out on a dataset where at least two `CPT` matches `Main_CPT` to make sure it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job (with `dplyr`):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
  group_by(Enc) %>%
  filter(any(CPT %in% lookup$Main_CPT)) %>%
  mutate(Flag = case_when(
    Paid_Status == "Paid" ~ "P",
    (CPT %in% lookup$Child_CPT) & (Paid_Status == "Non_Paid") ~ "A",
    !(CPT %in% lookup$Child_CPT) ~ "NP",
  ))
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   Enc [1]
    Enc   CPT Paid_Status  Flag
  <int> <chr>       <chr> <chr>
1 23349 99396        Paid     P
2 23349 36415    Non_Paid     A
3 23349 99000    Non_Paid    NP
```

**Data:**

```
df = read.table(text = "Enc     CPT     Paid_Status 
23345   97110   Paid    
23345   97140   Non_Paid
23349   99396   Paid
23349   36415   Non_Paid
23349   99000   Non_Paid
23354   99203O  Paid
23367   73030   Paid
23367   99024   Non_Paid
23372   99213O  Paid
23372   36415   Non_Paid
23382   81002   Non_Paid", header = TRUE)

lookup = read.table(text = "Main_CPT  Child_CPT
26010     01810
                    26010     99396
                    26010     0213T
                    26010     0216T
                    99396     64490
                    99396     36415
                    99396     64492
                    99396     64493
                    99396     64494
                    99396     64495
                    26034     64530
                    26034     69990
                    26034     36415
                    26034     99149
                    26034     99150", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
lookup = lookup %>% mutate_all(as.character)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot useR, that worked well for me with little modifications. Thanking you once again for your patience in making me clear with my query.

Comment: If I need to add another condition that, If any CPT of that Enc no. matched with Main_CPT and the paid status is "Non Paid", I need to mutate that case along with all the remaining CPTs for that Enc as "Review"??

Comment: @RAVI Just add the new condition in the `case_when` after `Paid_Status == "Paid" ~ "P"`.

Comment: I'm getting same output irrespective of adding the second condition after Paid_Status == "Paid" ~ "P" as suggested by you. Can u plz help me in dealing with this case?  when should I add another condition as stated: Paid_Status == "Non_Paid" ~ "Non_paid",
    (CPT %in% lookup$Child_CPT)  == "Review",
    !(CPT %in% lookup$Child_CPT) ~ "NP",
  ))

Comment: @RAVI Update your question and expected output to reflect the new conditions. It is generally discouraged to add additional requirements like this.

Comment: I have updated data sets along with desired output and re-framed my whole question for your easy understanding. Thanking you once again for your time and efforts for me.